# How is it possible python to be faster than pypy

Tags: python, pypy

I run a piece of code with python2.7 and the cProfile says 35s while cProfile on pypy says 73s ! How is that possible assuming pypy is faster interpreter. The code implements the BWT transformation on input a bitstream. I have two files: bwt.py which is called in fm.py. I  called the function as:

```
pypy -m cProfle fm.py inputfile
```

and then

```
python -m cProfle fm.py inputfile
```

The code from bwt.py is the following:

```
def rotations(t):
    ''' Return list of rotations of input string t '''
    tt = t * 2
    return [ tt[i:i+len(t)] for i in xrange(0, len(t)) ]

def bwm(t):
    return sorted(rotations(t))

def bwtViaBwm(t):
    ''' Given T, returns BWT(T) by way of the BWM '''
    return ''.join(map(lambda x: x[-1], bwm(t)))

def rankBwt(bw):
    ''' Given BWT string bw, return parallel list of B-ranks.  Also
        returns tots: map from character to # times it appears. '''
    tots = dict()
    ranks = []
    for c in bw:
        if c not in tots: tots[c] = 0
        ranks.append(tots[c])
        tots[c] += 1
    return ranks, tots
def firstCol(tots):
    ''' Return map from character to the range of rows prefixed by
        the character. '''
    first = {}
    totc = 0
    for c, count in sorted(tots.iteritems()):
        first[c] = (totc, totc + count)
        totc += count
    return first

def reverseBwt(bw):
    ''' Make T from BWT(T) '''
    ranks, tots = rankBwt(bw)
    first = firstCol(tots)
    rowi = 0 # start in first row
    t = '$' # start with rightmost character
    while bw[rowi] != '$':
        c = bw[rowi]
        t = c + t # prepend to answer
        # jump to row that starts with c of same rank
        rowi = first[c][0] + ranks[rowi]
    return t



def suffixArray(s):
    satups = sorted([(s[i:], i) for i in xrange(0, len(s))])
    print satups
    return map(lambda x: x[1], satups)

def bwtViaSa(t):
    # Given T, returns BWT(T) by way of the suffix array
    bw = []
    for si in suffixArray(t):
        if si == 0:
            bw.append('$')
        else:
            bw.append(t[si-1])
    return ''.join(bw) # return string-ized version of list bw



def readfile(sd):
    s=""
    with open(sd,'r') as myfile:
        s =myfile.read()
    return s.rstrip('\n')
def writefile(sd,N):
    with open(sd, "wb") as sink:
        sink.write(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in xrange(N)))
        sink.write('$')
    return



def main():
    data=readfile('inp')
    b=bwtViaBwm(data)
    ranks,tots = rankBwt(b)
    print "Input stream = "+ data
    print "BWT = " + bwtViaSa(data)
    print '\n'.join(bwm(data))
    print ("Lc ranking:")
    print zip(b,ranks) 

    fc=[x[0] for x in bwm(data)]
    fc= ''.join(fc)
    print ("First column="+ fc)
    ranks,tots = rankBwt(fc)
    print("Fc ranking:")
    print zip(fc,ranks) 

    print reverseBwt(bwtViaSa(data))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the code form the fm.py which i call it through pypy:

```
import bwt
import sys
from collections import Counter

def build_FM(fname):
    stream=bwt.readfile(fname)
    #print bwt.suffixArray(stream)
    b=bwt.bwtViaBwm(stream)
    ranks,tots = bwt.rankBwt(b)
    lc=zip(b,ranks)
    fc=[x[0] for x in bwt.bwm(stream)]
    fc= ''.join(fc)
    fc= zip(fc,ranks)
    #print lc,fc


def main():
    fname= sys.argv[1]
    build_FM(fname)
    return


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: post an example please

Comment: If it takes more time to run with pypy, then it would seem your assumption is incorrect .... for this particular code and data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Well i thought pypy is always faster. So i am wrong. I need to look for what kind of code pypy outperforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use PyPy over CPython if PyPy is 6.3 times faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946662/why-shouldnt-i-use-pypy-over-cpython-if-pypy-is-6-3-times-faster)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [PyPy significantly slower than CPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063508/pypy-significantly-slower-than-cpython).  One of the answers mentions "Profiling is known to slow PyPy a lot more than CPython."

Comment: From [PyPy's performance page](http://pypy.org/performance.html#id1): "turning on cProfile can distort the result (sometimes massively, though hopefully this should not be too common)."

Comment: @StevenRumbalski i tried the suggested vmprof to profile, but is not that helpful : http://vmprof.com/#/a3606fca8244aefe28537ba71f1e2790 . It does not say anything about running time

Answer (score 2):

Pypy does not guarantee faster execution of a program.

Firstly, the optimizations it implements take time (sometimes a significant amount of time) to run. Secondly, not all code will run faster under pypy, though most does.

Further, the relative speed of profiled code may well differ hugely between them - pypy code is low-level, and so introducing profiling is likely to slow it down (relatively speaking) more than CPython. What are the results without profiling active?

We'd need to see your program in order to provide much more information that that.

Comment: I edited my question with code

Answer (score -1):

Your script allocates an insane amount of memory in `rotations()` (O(N**2) where N is the size of the input file). As can be seen in cProfile and vmprof, most of the time is spent there.

What you're seeing is therefore differences in memory handling between PyPy and CPython. My guess is that you're swapping and that PyPy has a higher peak memory use.